# how to create a dataframe aggregating (grouping?) a dataframe containing only strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I would like to create a dataframe "aggregating" a larger data set.

Starting:

df:

```
  col1 col2 
1    A    B
2    A    C
3    A    B
```

and getting:

df_aggregated:

```
  col1  col2
1     A    B
2     A    C
```

without using any calclulation (count())

I would write:

df_aggreagated = df.groupby('col1')

but I do not get anything

print ( df_aggregated )

"error"

any help appreciated

Comment: Can you add more data? [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by simply dropping the duplicate entries using the `df.drop_duplicates` function:

```
df_aggregated = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1', 'col2'], keep=False)
print(df_aggregated)
   col1 col2
1    A    B
2    A    C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` with a function:

```
In [849]: df.groupby('col2', as_index=False).max()
Out[849]: 
  col2 col1
0    B    A
1    C    A
```